# How do you insert a string within a dynamic target using realloc()?

Tags: c

I'm struggling with memory allocation. I wanted to input a string into another and I made two functions that stop working at the same place - realloc. These functions are very similar. In first one I copy char by char into a temporary string and when I try to copy temporary string to the first one is the place where I get errors. In the second function I copy the end of first string (from the given position) to a temporary string, reallocate the first string (this is where I get errors) and remove everything in i from the given position. Then I append second string and temporary to a first string. Here is my code.
First function:

```
// str2 - is a string that I want to input in first string(str)
// at certain position (pos)

void ins (char **str, char *str2, int pos)
{
        // lenght of first and second strings
        int len = strlen(str[0]),
            len2 = strlen(str2),
            i, j, l = 0;

        // creating temporary string
        char *s = (char *) malloc ((len + len2) * sizeof(char));
        // copying first part of first string
        for (i = 0; i < pos; i++)
                s[i] = str[0][i];
        // copying second string
        for (j = 0; j < len2; j++)
                s[i + j] = str2[j]; 
        // copying second part of first string
        for (int k = pos; k < len; k++)
        {
                s[i + j + l] = str[0][k];
                l++;
        }

        // reallocating additional space for second string
        // and copying temporary string to first string
        str[0] = (char *) realloc (str[0], (len + len2) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(str[0], s);

        free(s);
        s = NULL;
}
```

Second function:

```
void ins2 (char **str,char *str2, int pos)
{
        // lenght of first and second string
        int len = strlen(str[0]),
            len2 = strlen(str2);

        // creating a temporary string and copying
        // from the given position
        char *s = (char *) malloc ((len - pos) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(s, str[0] + pos);

        // reallocating space for string that will be added
        // deleting part of it from the given position
        str[0] = (char *) realloc(str[0], (len + len2) * sizeof(char));
        str[0][pos] = '\0';

        // adding second string and temporary string
        strcat(str[0], str2);
        strcat(str[0], s);

        // be free, temporary string
        free(s);
        s = NULL;
}
```

Comment: For one, *none* of your allocations account for the terminating null char needed at the end of the string. A precise explanation of your input parameters, particularly the `pos` parameter and how it should be affecting the resultant string, is also warranted.

Comment: Well, in the first function I have printed the temporary string before copying and the output was good, but if I try to copy it to the first string I get memory errors.

Comment: "I get errors" is not all that helpful. It would improve your question if you described exactly what you're trying to achieve, and what exactly is going wrong when you try.

Comment: `char *s = (char *) malloc ((len + len2) * sizeof(char));` --> `char *s = malloc (len + len2 + 1);`  (Add 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing what I *think* you're trying to do, you need *one* `realloc()` for this, assuming the incoming string is indeed already dynamically allocated (it better be):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void ins (char **str, const char *str2, size_t pos)
{
    // lenght of first and second strings
    size_t len = strlen(*str);
    size_t len2 = strlen(str2);

    // reallocate new string
    char *tmp = realloc(*str, len + len2 + 1);
    if (tmp != NULL)
    {
        *str = tmp;
        memmove(tmp+pos+len2, tmp+pos, len-pos);
        memcpy(tmp+pos, str2, len2);
        tmp[len+len2] = 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *str = strdup("A simple string");
    char s2[] = "inserted ";

    printf("%s\n", str);
    ins(&str, s2, 9);
    printf("%s\n", str);

    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
A simple string
A simple inserted string
```

**How It Works**

- The passed-in strings are both sent through `strlen()` to obtain their lengths. Once we have those we know how large the resulting buffer needs to be.
- Once we `realloc()` the buffer, the original content is preserved, but we need to (possibly) shift content of the first string to open a hole for the second string. That shift, if done, may require overlapped memory be moved (as it does in the sample). For such memory copying, `memmove()` is used. Unlike `memcpy()`, the `memmove()` library function supports copying where the source and destination regions may overlap.
- Once the hole is made, we `memcpy()` the second string into position. There is no need for `strcpy()` since we already know the length.
- We finish by tacking the last slot to a terminating `0`, thereby finishing the null-terminated string and completing the operation

Note I made no affordances at all for this regarding someone passing an invalid `pos` (out of range), NULL strings, optimizing to nothing if `str2` is empty (or NULL), etc. That cleanup I leave to you, but I hope the idea of how this can be done is clear.

Comment: +1 Nicely done. `const`, `size_t`, +1 for `\0`,  etc.

Comment: @chux I gotta leave *something* for the OP to do. =P. Personally I'd use `pos = min(pos,len)` to allow someone to use UINT_MAX or some such to turn this into a glorified `strcat(),` but your observation is accurate regardless; +1.

Comment: I think I understood everything clearly and now have identical code in my program, but I still get errors:
*** glibc detected *** ./ins: realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x080489f5 ***
and my **str = 0x080489f5 I hope I've written it clearly :)

Comment: Agree to leave something for OP to do.  I amended my comment about 1 minute after posting to reflect that.  Like the `pos = min(pos,len)` idea.

Comment: @Skaiste You'll note how the sample posted includes a *dynamic* string passed by address on inception (the `strdup()` call effectively does a `malloc()` for the space required). So long as you pass the address of a pointer that holds a **dynamic** allocated string, (and the rest of the params are valid as noted above), the code should work. It will **NOT** work if the string passed is not dynamic.

Comment: yes, I understand that and have allocated that string myself. I don't know why, but strdup doesn't work for me, so I allocated it and then imputed, but it still doesn't want to work :(

Comment: oh no, my mistake, everything works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: @Skaiste Very glad it helped. Best of luck with this. If you have time, post the final result as an *amendment* to your question, including error checking, edge cases and how they're accounted for, etc. Future readers will likely find it informative. Thanks again.